# How to flush data while inserting in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ai-platform

I am inserting a row into BigQuery using the following code:

```
rows = [self.__dict__]
errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, rows)
```

It is being inserted into the streaming buffer and I am able to fetch from it. I want to modify a field of this data. How do I flush the data into the DB?

Comment: BigQuery is not very well suited for updates. What we do, is to insert new versions instead of doing updates. That, of course, will result in some extra lines in queries for selecting data, but it's doable. BR

Comment: @RoarS. Why isn't update supported in BigQuery? What use case does this serve?

Comment: BigQuery is made for data analysis (OLAP). If you try to use it like Postgres (OLTP), you will quickly run into problems. BigQuery supports update, but the use case is then to update many records. Typical delay before you can do update/delete on data, will be 15-30 minutes after insert. Single inserts should work fine (based on my experience in a current project). BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @[Roar S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072498/roar-s), Suggestion for better visibility for the community. @[Roar S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072498/roar-s). is correct  BQ supports update query but not recommended for large scale transactions. BigQuery is an [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) database where it is focused on analytical and reporting purposes while the latter [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) is more used for transactional processing.

This I believe a good reference for comparison of both databases: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Technical-Tips-Tricks/DATABASE-Concept-Database-structures-OLTP-vs-OLAP/ta-p/592445/jump-to/first-unread-message